# Batch Unrar after check file extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, unrar

i am trying to Unrar 400 files via `batch` script.
in my folder files mixed with videos
some file name is "love.blood.repack.mp4"
i have add *.r* for find rar file in my script
but script show with videos file like "love.blood`.r`epack.mp4"

how to check if extension have .rar .r001 .r01 .r02 etc and then run unrar ?
only check extension not full file name

```
c:\unrar.bat c:\mymixedfolder
```

My windows .bat batch script

```
@echo off &setlocal
set /a nfile=0
echo Copying directory structure from %1 to %2 ...
xcopy /T "%~1" "%~2"
REM walk directory structure and convert each file in quiet mode
set "sourcefolder=%~1"
set "targetfolder=%~2"
for /R "%sourcefolder%" %%a in (*.r*) do (
    echo converting "%%~nxa" ...
    set "sourcefile=%%~fa"
    set "sourcepath=%%~dpa"
    set "targetfile=%%~na.flv"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "targetfolder=%targetfolder%!sourcepath:%sourcefolder%=!"
    echo "%%~nxa"
    endlocal
    set /A nfile+=1
)
echo Done! Unrar %nfile% file(s)
```

Comment: You don't actually start unrarring .r01 volumes ect. Always start from the .rar file. Everything from the same set will be extracted. Something like .r001 does not exist (after .r99 it becomes s00), but .001 RARs do. You'll want to start extracting only from .part01.rar, .rar and .001 files.

Comment: @Gfy yes but i need this because i want to delete rar (all) files after extract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL disableDelayedExpansion
SET "sourcefolder=."
FOR /R "%sourcefolder%" %%a IN (*.r*) DO (
    FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('echo %%~xa^|findstr /r "\.r.*"') DO ECHO %%~a
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "sourcefolder=."
FOR /R "%sourcefolder%" %%a IN (*.r??) DO (
    if /i "%%~xa"==".rar" DO ECHO %%~a
)
```